# OO: Can an interface implement another interface?

Tags: architecture, user-interface, oop

I know it is language-specific, but is it possible in OO-languages that interfaces implement other interfaces?

Comment: is this language agnositic or language specific? Are you asking for an answer for every OO language?

Comment: @Matt Lacey. No I'm just asking if it  possible in any OO language

Comment: Perhaps this is more a question about abstract object-oriented principles? Would it be *theoretically* possible for an interface to implement another interface?

Comment: helpful question can be found here to http://stackoverflow.com/q/8531292/1055241

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in C# you can do:

```
interface YourInterface: IDisposable {
   /// your methods
}
```

and a class wich implements `YourInterface` shall also implement `IDisposable`'s method.

Of course, then this is valid:

```
YourInterface implementation = new Implementation();
IDiposable disposable = implementation;
```

Comment: @Rofl: I've only ever seen the term "super interface" applied to Java, and I'm not a Java developer. What exactly does it mean, and if you're more comfortable with that language, why not ask the question specifically about Java?

Comment: @Roflcoptr you name it. The point is that an object which implements YourInterface *is a" IDisposable too.

Answer (score 5):

interface can extend but not implement another interface, since there is no implementation in the interface.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, though the term used is "extend" rather than "implement."

Answer (score 0):

In simple words Implementation means applying set of predefined rules.interface is same like this.so an interface can not implement other interface.thats why we extend one interface with other